# Opencart - adding products gives error

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, opencart

There is already a product in the catalog. When I try to add another one, it returns this error: (which i think is SQL)
Notice: Error: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'
    Error No: 1062

```
`INSERT INTO oc_product SET model = 'xxxxx', sku = '', upc = '', ean = '', jan = '', isbn = '', mpn = '', location = '', quantity = '1', minimum = '1', subtract = '1', stock_status_id = '5', date_available = '2015-04-03', manufacturer_id = '0', shipping = '1', price = '0', points = '0', weight = '0', weight_class_id = '1', length = '0', width = '0', height = '0', length_class_id = '1', status = '1', tax_class_id = '0', sort_order = '1', date_added = NOW()`
```

in /home/xxxx/xxxx/system/database/mysql.php on line 50

Any Ideas?
I think that 2147483647 is the max value the id can take, but for some reason that's all it tries to auto fill?

Comment: That syntax sounds like a merge of an insert and update. Can you post your code? That integer is the largest integer (32 bit) you can have, is that actually the product's id?

Comment: @chris85 I don't know where the code is being executed from - it's part of the opencart framework. But if I look into the SQL database with phpmyadmin, that ID does indeed already exist. I don't understand why it doesn't start with 1,2,3... - or maybe the PHP code tries to put a  negative ID (for any bizarre reason) which sql assumes the max possible?

Comment: I am guessing `primary` is an `auto_increment` column. In that case, the following MySql documentation provides a couple possible solutions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: The AUTO_INCREMENT is the value which mySQL uses for a table to auto fill for when INSERTing new rows. So, the next ID will be the value of AUTO_INCREMENT. (Which, was incorrectly set as 2147483647).

So I went to phpMyAdmin and changed the auto_increment back to 1, for the products table, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

OR Other bug in tbl Oc_card no Auto_increment on row card_id.
Set Auto_increment on the row card_id
And FIX IT